# linux asm x86 producing segfault

Tags: linux, assembly, x86

I am learning a bit of assembler for linux and I have this example program that is just supposed to call the write syscall and print 'Hello, World!'on the screen, however it produces a segfault.  I'm learning in my free time, not homework, I no longer go to school!

Can anybody see anything wrong with this code?

```
xor eax,eax
xor ebx,ebx
xor ecx,ecx
xor edx,edx
jmp short string
code:
pop     ecx
mov     bl,1
mov     dl,13
mov     al,4
int     0x80
dec     bl
mov     al,1
int     0x80
string:
call code
db      'Hello, World!'
```

Comment: I must say, that's a fairly unusual method of loading the address of your string into `ecx`.

Comment: Does it produce the output and THEN segfault, or produce no output before segfaulting?

Comment: @Greg: agreed, though it is one of the most common methods of writing position independent shellcode...

Answer (score 2):

Works for me. Here's what I did (note, I'm on a 64-bit machine so I have an extra flag to create a 32-bit binary):

test.asm

```
_start:
xor eax,eax
xor ebx,ebx
xor ecx,ecx
xor edx,edx
jmp short string
code:
pop     ecx
mov     bl,1
mov     dl,13
mov     al,4
int     0x80
dec     bl
mov     al,1
int     0x80
string:
call code
db      'Hello, World!'
```

commands:

```
$ nasm -felf test.asm -o test.o
$ gcc -m32 -nostdlib -nostdinc test.o -o test
```

which produced a warning, but that's ok.

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.1/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000008048080
```

Then I ran:

```
$ ./test
```

and it indeed output `"Hello, World!"` (without a newline). No segfault.

Comment: It looks like that was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with linux assembly, but here is a guess:

When calling APIs, you have to use a specific calling convention. One of the things that are specified by a convention is the list of registers that are preserved across the API call. In your case, the error is using `dec bl` instead of `xor ebx, ebx`. Because `bl` is used as input parameter, it's quite unlikely that it will be preserved. The same for `mov al, 1`, it's safer to write `mov eax, 1`

And I'm agree with @Greg Hewgil, your way of obtaining the address of string is quite unusual. The common way to write position independent code with strings is this:

```
...
call my_print
db 'hello world!', 0
...

my_print:
pop ecx
xor edx, edx
lp:
cmp byte [ecx + edx], 0
inc edx
jne lp
lea eax, [ecx + edx] 
push eax // return address
dec edx
mov eax, 4
int 0x80
ret
```

Comment: your "common" way is not particularly different that the OP. You are still doing a `jmp` to just before the data and doing a `call` right back finally doing a `pop` to get the address of the data into a register. The only difference is how you are using the register after all of that.

Comment: @Evan Teran: the difference is that the string appears where it is used, and the length is computed automaticaly.

Comment: I could hardly call a loop which searches for `'\0'` "automatic".

Answer (score 0):

This code is likely to crash if compiled and run under a 64bit kernel.  The 64bit return address will not fit into the 32bit ecx register, you would have to pop rcx instead.  Furthermore, this code uses the 32bit API, which may not be available under a 64bit kernel.  You should use the 64bit API instead, as described in my blog post: [x86-64 assembly on Linux](http://callumscode.com/blog/3).